# Gerando PDF com Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

Estou tentando implementar essa lib de pdf para o meu projeto Laravel: https://tcpdf.org/.
Sendo que estou com problemas na implementação, por conta da documentação dela não ser muito clara com o método que preciso usar para criar um PDF.

Comment: Que problemas ? Tem algum código ? 

Eu sugiro que em vez de usar a lib original, use uma versão adaptada para o Laravel, veja [isso](https://github.com/elibyy/tcpdf-laravel).

Comment: Hum, os métodos para implementar não está claro. Meu pdf vai conter dados de uma sessão de pedidos, isso integrando com QRCODE, sendo que o problema é o PDF, como gerar ele.

Answer (score 1):

Para implementar, como você está usando um framework, eu sugeriria instalar através do composer.

Primeiro, adicione ao `composer.json` a dependencia do TCPDF:

```
"require": {
    // Aqui terá todas as dependencias do Laravel, coloque em baixo o tcpdf.
    "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "^6.2.13"
}
```

Depois, execute o comando `composer install` se houver o arquivo `composer.lock`, caso contrário, use `composer update`.

Para utilizar o TCPDF, seria mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php
// Acredito que não será necessário a etapa abaixo, mas faça o teste com ou sem.
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$pdf = new TCPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Write(1, 'Hello world');

$pdf->Output('hello_world.pdf');

?>
```

[Fonte original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47379995/8741188)

Exemplos de como usar a biblioteca [aqui](https://tcpdf.org/examples/).

Comment: https://blog.especializati.com.br/gerar-pdf-no-laravel-com-dompdf/

Answer (score 0):

Te recomendo utilizar a DOMPdf, que já é amplamente aceita e utilizada na comunidade Laravel.

Além disso, é de fácil instalação e possui uma ótima documentação.

Vale dar uma conferida:
   https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf